# std::shared_ptr::owner_before and std::owner_less: What exactly is meant by "owner-based order"?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have found a few discussions on this but nothing appears to ever specify what "owner based order" actually is.

Is it effectively evaluating `<` on the value of the owned pointer memory addresses?

Answer (score 11):

It defines an arbitrary strict weak ordering under which two pointers are equivalent if and only if they share ownership or are both empty.

Equivalence is defined in the usual way:

```
bool equivalent(p1, p2) {
    return !p1.owner_before(p2) && !p2.owner_before(p1);
}
```

This doesn't necessarily mean that they point to the same object. Two pointers can point to different objects but still share ownership:

```
struct thing {int n;};
shared_ptr<thing> t1 = make_shared<thing>();
shared_ptr<int>   t2(t1, &t1->n);

assert(t1 != t2);          // point to different objects
assert(equivalent(t1,t2)); // share ownership
```

Likewise, two pointers can point to the same object without sharing:

```
thing t;
shared_ptr<thing> t1(&t, some_deleter());
shared_ptr<thing> t2(&t, some_deleter());

assert(t1 == t2);            // point to the same object
assert(!equivalent(t1, t2)); // don't share ownership
```

(Of course, this would be disastrous with the default deleter since both would try to delete the object; but there are sensible applications for this kind of thing with a suitable custom deleter).

In practice, this could be implemented by comparing the address of the internal structure used for the shared reference count.

Answer (score 4):

Semantically, it means that two `shared_ptr`s compare equal if an only if they share ownership or are both `nullptr`, and otherwise there is some consistent ordering of `shared_ptr`s.

Effectively, this ordering is implemented by comparing the internal pointer to the reference control block that is shared between `shared_ptr`s that "share ownership." Note that it is possible to create `shared_ptr`s with differing `get()` that share ownership via the constructor:

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

Which is useful, e.g, for handing out pointers to members of an object held by `shared_ptr`.

Comment: +1 good point about `shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );`.

Comment: Yup, I had picked up the point about how this is intended to work well alongside that aliasing constructor of `shared_ptr`, however it still sounds excessively vague to just say that there exists some consistent ordering. E.g. what kind of timescale am I to expect this ordering not to change...? It doesn't answer the question of am I supposed to just treat this as though it's comparing the pointer values themselves?

Comment: @StevenLu: The ordering is unspecified, but won't change during the lifetimes of the shared objects - once you've established that one pointer comes before another, then that won't change. It's not the same as comparing the pointer values.