# On the implementation of atomic_exchange_strong_explicit for shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

Please see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_atomic.h;h=d05d6865575306c243991c7642e13b20245c894c;hb=c8f03f886912cf080ad33cec47e67a7f168bc555#l207) link:

```
template<typename _Tp>
  bool
  atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(shared_ptr<_Tp>* __p,
                                          shared_ptr<_Tp>* __v,
                                          shared_ptr<_Tp> __w,
                                          memory_order,
                                          memory_order)
  {
    shared_ptr<_Tp> __x; // goes out of scope after __lock
    _Sp_locker __lock{__p, __v};
    owner_less<shared_ptr<_Tp>> __less;
    if (*__p == *__v && !__less(*__p, *__v) && !__less(*__v, *__p))
      {
        __x = std::move(*__p);
        *__p = std::move(__w);
        return true;
      }
    __x = std::move(*__v);
    *__v = *__p;
    return false;
  }
```

To me it looks like `*__p == *__v` and `!__less(*__p, *__v) && !__less(*__v, *__p)` both state the fact that the pointers `*__p` and `*__v` are equal. Why are they both used there?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834131/stdshared-ptrowner-before-and-stdowner-less-what-exactly-is-meant-by-own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As touched on [by this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21834508/1870760) we need to both be sure that both `shared_ptrs` share the same object and share the same ownership of that object ( do both shared pointers use the same ref counter ? ).

`*__p == *__v` checks the first part by comparing `*__p.get() == *__v.get()` and then `!__less(*__p, *__v) && !__less(*__v, *__p)` makes sure that both shared pointers share the internal ref counter, thus satisfying both parts.

`*__p == *__v` only checks for equality of the owned objects, not for a shared state of the internal ref counter which is what we need here, this is why we need the extra construct.